# Node + Express.js:how pass variable to a a route?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express-generator for the first time

So I have

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

I've added the iniparser

```
var iniparser = require('iniparser');
var config = iniparser.parseSync('./config.ini');
```

In the routes/index.js I've tried this

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next, config) {
    res.render('index', { title:config.title, message:config.message });
});
```

But I got

```
404 Error: Not Found
   at app.use.res.render.message (C:\Users\realtebo\Documents\node\auto- express\app.js:36:15)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second paramater of the route call :

```
router.get('/', config, function(req, res, next, config) {
...
```

But I think the best solution is to declare variables in the function scope :

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next, config) {
    var iniparser = require('iniparser');
    var config = iniparser.parseSync('./config.ini'); 
    res.render('index', { title:config.title, message:config.message });
});
```

And the very best way is to declare your route code in another file

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, the routes are in a fidderent, away from the 'bootstrap' of the app, where i read the inifile. This is the reason I must pass the config object to this route. (ok, I must pass only one property, but the question is the same)